# Combine the results of a CAT and TAC in a single window in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, cat, watch

I have two log files which I would like to view on my screen simultaneously. Below you can see my commands:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ watch -n 1 tac /home/pi/log/log.txt
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ watch -n 1 cat /home/pi/log/heartbeat.txt
```

Do I have to write a program to do that or can I do it through `bash`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`, both of which have a "split screen" mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`multiwatch`](http://www.makelinux.com/man/1/M/multiwatch) like this; first update your repo list like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now search the repos for `multiwatch` to make sure it is available:

```
apt-cache search multiwatch
```

Once you have confirmed it’s available to your install of Raspbian on your Raspberry Pi, just install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install multiwatch
```